# Edit row information using BDC

Tags: 2010, external-content-type, bdc, datatable, custom-bdc

I want to make simple database table insert/edit/delete using BDC.

What I have tried:
I have created External Content type mapped to database table and using external content type created list. But BDC list control is read-only and I want to perform insert/edit/delete using BDC & Sharepoint Designer.

Any help pls!

Comment: BDC (Business Data Catalog) was in SP 2007 and provided read only access. BCS (Business Connectivity Services) is in SP 2010 and has both read and write. Are you using 2010/BCS or 2007/BDC?

Comment: I am using 2010/BCS

Comment: Does the database account that is being used by the external system (the external system your external content type uses) have write access to the database?

Comment: The database account has write access.